# comparison(4) is only possible for atomic and list types

Tags: atomic

I have a 54x2 character matrix(totallist) which stores the locations of different input files. I've declared a function inside which I've a loop wherein row by row values are extracted from the 54x2 character matrix, stored in a data frame(named ACC) and then subsetting is done.

```
names(read.delim(totallist[1,1]))
[1] "stock" "firstsymbol" "date" "dhm" "nooftrades" "totqty" "openprice" "closeprice" "highprice"  
[10] "lowprice" "wtdavgprice" "modeprice"
```

Below is the function declaration: I pass totallist as an argument

```
function (y) 
{
    for(i in 1:54)
    {
        ACC <- read.delim(y[i,1])
        Acc.sub=subset(ACC,date<=20100331 & dhm%%10000<1531 & date!=20100206,select=c(dhm,closeprice))
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error message:

Error in date <= 20100331 : 
  comparison (4) is possible only for atomic and list types